# Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s): eth_sendRawTransaction

Tags: .net, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I want to SignContract and then SendTracsaction,

```
var mintMsg = new TransferFunction()
        {
            TokenAmount = 1,
            To = "0x6f78e96E4cDeca2F1e121f23Bc2effBaaea05E8f",
            Nonce = 57,
            GasPrice = 5,
            Gas = 70000
        };
        var txHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionHandler<TransferFunction>();
        var signedTx = await txHandler.SignTransactionAsync(contractAddress, mintMsg);

        // Attempt #1
        var txReceipt = await web3.Eth.Transactions.SendRawTransaction.SendRequestAsync(signedTx);
        // Attempt #2
        TransactionInput transactionInput = new TransactionInput()
            {
                ChainId = new HexBigInteger(Web3.Convert.ToWei(56, UnitConversion.EthUnit.Wei)),
                Gas = new HexBigInteger(Web3.Convert.ToWei(70000, UnitConversion.EthUnit.Wei)),
                GasPrice = new HexBigInteger(Web3.Convert.ToWei(5, UnitConversion.EthUnit.Wei)),
                Nonce = new HexBigInteger(await GetTransactionCount()),
                To = "0x6f78e96E4cDeca2F1e121f23Bc2effBaaea05E8f",
                Data = signedTx,
                Value = new HexBigInteger(100),

            };
        var txReceipt2 = await web3.Eth.Transactions.SendTransaction.SendRequestAsync(transactionInput);
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have the same issue, and this code working for me**

```
var privateKey = _user.PrivateKey;
var account = new Account(privateKey);
var web3 = new Web3(account, "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/");
```